# why wont my background load?

Tags: image, background, background-image

all of a sudden, my background image wont load.
so i created a test site.
its basic.
the background shows up on my local host but not when i upload it to dreamhost.
i cant understand what the problem is. can anyone shed some light?
the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>TEST TEST TEST</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

the CSS:

```
body {
    background:url(images/redeemer.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
```

here is the link;

www.eddiemilladesign.com

i can understand what the problem is, ive used this method over and over again and never had a problem.
please help.
-eddie

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome and you press Alt + Ctrl + J (to bring up the console), you can see the browser is getting a 403 forbidden error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`

Make sure the web server is running under an account that has the necessary permissions to access the background file.

Comment: THANKS! it worked! i changed the permissions (in cyberduck) and it running now....

Comment: Good. FYI It's better to use upvote/mark as answer instead of using comments for thanking people.